# unable to plot two columns from DataFrame after using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to plot two columns that have been read in using pandas.read_csv, the code:-

```
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot

data = read_csv('Stats.csv', sep=',')
#data = data.astype(float)
data.plot(x = 1, y = 2)

pyplot.show()
```

the csv file snippet:-

```
1,a4,2000,125,1.9,2.8,25.6
2,a4,7000,125,1.7,2.3,18
3,a2,7000,30,0.84,1.1,8.11
4,a2,5000,30,0.83,1.05,6.87
5,a2,4000,45,2.8,3.48,16.54
```

when x = 1 and y = 2 it will plot the second column against the fourth not the third as I expected

When I try to plot the third column against the fourth (x = 2, y = 3) it plots the third against the fifth

I'm trying to plot the third against the fourth right now, when both x and y = 2 it will plot the third column against the fourth but the values are incorrect, what am I missing? is the read_csv changing the order of the columns?

Comment: Tried df.plot(x='col_name_1', y='col_name_2') ?

Comment: A workaround I found is to give `names=range(number_of_columns)` to  the `read_csv` function. But I can't explain why the automatic labeling works differently. The `y` coordinate behaves as an offset from the `x` coordinated, i.e. it selects `x+y` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input csv is without headers which doesn't help clarity (see Murali's comment). But I think the problem stems from the nature of column that contains a4,a2.

This column can be used for the x axis but not for y axis (non-numeric data on an x axis appears to be just read in order). Hence the count offset. So as y "reads over" the column at 1 (all 0 indexed) - but x does not.

Conducting

```
 data.plot(x=1,y=0)
```

and

```
data.plot(x=0,y=1)
```

and inspecting the axis helps visualise what's going on.

Bizarrely this means you can do

```
 df.plot(x=1,y=1)
```

to get what you want.

Comment: Thank you, the original csv did have headers but I couldn't include them, I didn't realise it would read over the column with a2 and 4, thanks for clarifying that for me its working now